# Why is Putty not connecting to EC2 instance after stop/start?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, putty

I wanted to programmatically start and stop `EC2 Instance` using `lambda` function. The functions worked successfully but once the EC2 instance is started, I'm not able to connect it through `Putty`, it says `Connection Timed Out` while the EC2 dashboard says `running` in the instance's status

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start investigating by right-clicking on the instance in AWS Console and choosing "Get System Logs". There might be startup problems.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

1) whenever you stop and start the aws servers the **public ip will changes** so make sure you are using new public ip and the **same key** which is used while creating

2)make sure you **white listed you ip address in the security group** of the same server 
   to get your your ip address search in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=ZppiW5mACIrZvgSKjKy4DQ&q=my%20ip%20&oq=my%20ip%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131k1l2j0l5j0i10k1j0l2.1085.2510.0.2772.7.6.0.0.0.0.122.468.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.5.468.0..35i39k1.0.9H0_P0dnWY8) with this key word `my ip` and white list that ip in inbound rules of the security group

3) you can try to connect your server through **VPN** (if you had one)

Comment: Please don't post links like that; it's not that we don't know how to find Google. More than half the people who visit Stack Overflow actually *come* via Google.

Comment: sure @Glorfindel i have removed the link

Answer (score 1):

It is because your Public IP has been changed once you start/stop an EC2 instance. If you attach an elastic IP to your running EC2 instance, it won't change. You've only open traffic for your Public IP(previous) in the security group. After restarting  EC2 instance, your machine's Public IP address needs to get updated in the security group.

Above reasons might be cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Public DNS` changes everytime, was connecting to the old public DNS

Comment: If this is the answer, the please click the green check mark to close the question.